# Magento2.3.2 admin panel is not opening after entered login credentials but website works fine

Tags: admin, admin-panel, magento2.3.2

Suddenly my website's admin panel is not opening after entered login credentials but the website works fine. When I tried to access my admin panel from the browser, I am getting the following error.

Please check the following screenshot :

[image]

I opened the log file, And there is an error like the following:

> {"0":"Specified invalid parent id
>   (Webkul_Marketplace::marketplace)","1":"
>
> ```
> #1
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->___callParent('getResult',
>   array(&Magento\Backend\Model\Menu#000000003e253edf0000000007aab923#))
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#2
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Backend\Model\Menu#000000003e253edf0000000007aab923#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#3
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getResult',
>   array(&Magento\Backend\Model\Menu#000000003e253edf0000000007aab923#),
>   array(array('SetupMenuBuilder'))) called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Menu/Builder/Interceptor.php:39]\n#4
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->getResult(&Magento\Backend\Model\Menu#000000003e253edf0000000007aab923#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Menu/Config.php:148]\n#5
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Config->_initMenu() called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Menu/Config.php:111]\n#6
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Config->getMenu() called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Url.php:364]\n#7
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Url->_getMenu() called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Url.php:324]\n#8
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Url->getStartupPageUrl() called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:281]\n#9
>   Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->_processUrlKeys() called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php:50]\n#10
>   Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->_processUrlKeys()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Request/BackendValidator.php:175]\n#11
>   Magento\Backend\App\Request\BackendValidator->validate(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e253d9d0000000007aab923#,
>   &Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor#000000003e253ec70000000007aab923#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/CompositeValidator.php:40]\n#12
>   Magento\Framework\App\Request\CompositeValidator->validate(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e253d9d0000000007aab923#,
>   &Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor#000000003e253ec70000000007aab923#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:138]\n#13
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e253d9d0000000007aab923#,
>   &Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor#000000003e253ec70000000007aab923#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:99]\n#14
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e253d9d0000000007aab923#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]\n#15
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e253d9d0000000007aab923#))
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#16
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e253d9d0000000007aab923#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#17
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e253d9d0000000007aab923#),
>   array(array('default_store_se...', 'page_cache_from_...',
>   'storeCookieValid...', 'install', 'configHash'))) called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]\n#18
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e253d9d0000000007aab923#)
>   called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:137]\n#19
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]\n#20
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]\n#21
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000003e253de30000000007aab923#)
>   called at
>   [index.php:39]\n</pre>","url":"/admin/","script_name":"/index.php"}
> ```

**My menu.xml file is as follows:**

`<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">

    <menu>    
        <add id="Webkul_Marketplace::marketplace" title="Marketplace Management" module="Webkul_Marketplace" sortOrder="10" resource="Webkul_Marketplace::marketplace"/>
        <add id="Webkul_Marketplace::product" title="Manage Product" module="Webkul_Marketplace" sortOrder="1" parent="Webkul_Marketplace::menu" action="marketplace/product" resource="Webkul_Marketplace::product"/>
        <add id="Webkul_Marketplace::seller" title="Manage Seller" module="Webkul_Marketplace" sortOrder="1" parent="Webkul_Marketplace::menu" action="marketplace/seller" resource="Webkul_Marketplace::seller"/>    
        <add id="Webkul_Marketplace::commission" title="Manage Commission" module="Webkul_Marketplace" sortOrder="1" parent="Webkul_Marketplace::menu" action="marketplace/commission" resource="Webkul_Marketplace::commission"/>    
        <add id="Webkul_Marketplace::transaction" title="Sellers Transaction" module="Webkul_Marketplace" sortOrder="1" parent="Webkul_Marketplace::menu" action="marketplace/transaction" resource="Webkul_Marketplace::transaction"/>
        <add id="Webkul_Marketplace::feedback" title="Manage Feedback" module="Webkul_Marketplace" sortOrder="1" parent="Webkul_Marketplace::menu" action="marketplace/feedback" resource="Webkul_Marketplace::feedback"/>
        <add id="Webkul_Marketplace::menu" title="Menu" module="Webkul_Marketplace" sortOrder="10" parent="Webkul_Marketplace::marketplace" dependsOnModule="Webkul_Marketplace" resource="Webkul_Marketplace::marketplace"/>    
    </menu>    
</config>`

**My di.xml file is as follows:**

https://we.tl/t-KXppIOunZJ

**My System.xml file is as follows:**

https://we.tl/t-W83kxQxnNY

Comment: can you please share your system.xml and di.xml file

Comment: The login page of the admin panel is opening fine. Are you getting the error after login?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora, Yes, I edited the question

Comment: @MoinMalek, Yeah sure but Location of the required files?

Comment: Please upload your Webkul_Marketplace extension's system.xml file

Comment: @TejaBhagavanKollepara Please Share Webkul/Marketplace/etc/system.xml and  Webkul/Marketplace/etc/di.xml

Comment: Check my example and see in your menu.xml and compare it.

Comment: @RohanHapani, Updated, please check once

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, it seems that some menu item is trying to use menu resource **`Webkul_Marketplace::marketplace`**, but there is no parent id like **`Webkul_Marketplace::marketplace`**, so it will throw the error.

Please check the place from where **`Webkul_Marketplace::marketplace`** is being referenced, and check whether **`Webkul_Marketplace::marketplace`** is defined in the menu.xml file of Webkul extension.

If not, then change the reference from **`Webkul_Marketplace::marketplace`** to some other existing resource ID.

I hope it makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi,
Please change the menu.xml file as below.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">

    <menu>    
        <add id="Webkul_Marketplace::marketplace" title="Marketplace Management" module="Webkul_Marketplace" sortOrder="10" resource="Webkul_Marketplace::management"/>
        <add id="Webkul_Marketplace::product" title="Manage Product" module="Webkul_Marketplace" sortOrder="1" parent="Webkul_Marketplace::menu" action="marketplace/product" resource="Webkul_Marketplace::product"/>
        <add id="Webkul_Marketplace::seller" title="Manage Seller" module="Webkul_Marketplace" sortOrder="1" parent="Webkul_Marketplace::menu" action="marketplace/seller" resource="Webkul_Marketplace::seller"/>    
        <add id="Webkul_Marketplace::commission" title="Manage Commission" module="Webkul_Marketplace" sortOrder="1" parent="Webkul_Marketplace::menu" action="marketplace/commission" resource="Webkul_Marketplace::commission"/>    
        <add id="Webkul_Marketplace::transaction" title="Sellers Transaction" module="Webkul_Marketplace" sortOrder="1" parent="Webkul_Marketplace::menu" action="marketplace/transaction" resource="Webkul_Marketplace::transaction"/>
        <add id="Webkul_Marketplace::feedback" title="Manage Feedback" module="Webkul_Marketplace" sortOrder="1" parent="Webkul_Marketplace::menu" action="marketplace/feedback" resource="Webkul_Marketplace::feedback"/>
        <add id="Webkul_Marketplace::menu" title="Menu" module="Webkul_Marketplace" sortOrder="10" parent="Webkul_Marketplace::marketplace" dependsOnModule="Webkul_Marketplace" resource="Webkul_Marketplace::marketplaceresource"/>    
    </menu>    
</config>
```

Please check it

Thanks

Comment: No change, same error

Comment: remove this <add id="Webkul_Marketplace::menu" title="Menu" module="Webkul_Marketplace" sortOrder="10" parent="Webkul_Marketplace::marketplace" dependsOnModule="Webkul_Marketplace" resource="Webkul_Marketplace::marketplaceresource"/>